# How to fix this histogram so that the bars are equidistant and the labels are in the center of the bars.?

Tags: matplotlib, plot

[image]

The title explains it all. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Would you mind providing a snippet of code which reproduces the graph ?

Comment: def syndPlt(columnName, pltTitle,xLabel, yLabel):
        # Distribution based on continent
        columnList = df[columnName]
        columnList = columnList.tolist()
        #Plot
        n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x=columnList, bins='auto', align='mid')
        plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.75)
        plt.xlabel(xLabel)
        plt.ylabel(yLabel)
        plt.title(pltTitle)
        plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
        maxfreq = n.max()

Answer (score 1):

Based on the piece of code you provided, this snippet below should achieve what you want. The idea is to provide manually the bins location, set the width of each bar and align everything left. More information [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
columnList = []
for i in range(32):
    columnList.append('Asia')
for i in range(58):
    columnList.append('Europe')
for i in range(18):
    columnList.append('North America')
for i in range(12):
    columnList.append('Central or\nSouth America')
for i in range(7):
    columnList.append('Australia or\nOceania')
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x=columnList, bins=numpy.arange(6), rwidth=0.5,
                            align='left')
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.75)
plt.xlabel('Continents')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Continental Distribution of respondents')
plt.show()
```

[image]